# How to fix a menu on the left side and main content to the right

Tags: html, css

I wanna have menu fixed on the left side of the page occupying 20% of the width and the content on the right side occupying the rest 80%.like this:

[image]

At the moment, my setup looks like the following which I don't want:

[image]

I tried using floats to separate both container but its not really working.

```
header#masthead {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #232323;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

How can I put the menu on   the side bar(left) and the rest of the website on content the right?

Here my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/4bv9h7ed/1/

Comment: If you want menu to be appeared at left and image at right then please follow the same placement of HTML elements html pages.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0s08bt7n/1/] custom left menu html & css maybe looking something like this one ??

Comment: @ Mostafa Baezid.jsfiddle doesn''t really open.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need. Make sure you are using bootstrap with this.

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Comment: I won't use bootstrap but already inspected the link from your answer and seems to be quite simple to do.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to make a new div with `.container` class, as the main div. Then, you have to put your header inside it and a brand new div which is going to handle the content on the right side. All you have to do now is to prepare the css, by setting the `display: flex` of the main container and the width's of both children divs.

Just check the snippet carefully and I'm sure you will be able to do it by yourself next time.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.main-navigation li {
  border-top: 1px solid #eeb422;
  padding: 7px;
}
.main-navigation li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeb422;
}
.main-navigation a {} #home {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
header {
  width: 30vw;
}
.mainContent {
  width: 70vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>



  <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="site-branding">
      <figure>
        <a href="http://localhost/cigarros/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">
          <img width="261" height="150" src="http://pets.petsmart.com/services/_images/grooming/dog/m_t/dog-aromatherapy.jpg" class="custom-logo" alt="cropped-cigarros.jpg" itemprop="logo" />
        </a>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!-- .site-branding -->

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
      <!--                    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>-->
      <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26">
            <a href="http://localhost/cigarros/about-us/">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">
            <a href="http://localhost/cigarros/products/">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24">
            <a href="http://localhost/cigarros/contact/">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- #site-navigation -->
  </header>
  <!-- #masthead -->

  <div id="content" class="site-content">


    <section id="home">


    </section>

  </div>


  <div class='mainContent'>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a wrapper for both the `.site-header` element and the `.site-content` element and add `display: flex` to the wrapper CSS properties.
This way the `.site-header` element will be on the same row as the `.site-content`.

Now you can just modify the width of your elements to the desired value.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h1mc02jp/2/) is a jsfiddle based on yours.

Comment: There was a mistake in the link to my jsFiddle. Edited :-)